# Find basis and degree of splitting field of degree 8 (another question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

Problem: Find degree and basis of splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $f=X^4-2$.

My attempt:

$X^4-2$ has $4$ roots: $\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{2}\omega, \sqrt[4]{2}\omega^2 ,\sqrt[4]{2}\omega^3$

Hence, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since $i\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ we get by tower's law:

$|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i):\mathbb{Q}|=4(2)=8$

Therefore,

$\{1 , \sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{4},\sqrt[4]{8},i, i\sqrt[4]{2},i \sqrt[4]{4}, i \sqrt[4]{8}\}$ is a basis.

Is my conclusion and proof correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!

Definitely $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i]$, so your set is generating $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Since the $\mathbb{Q}$-diemension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ (i.e., the degree of the extension) is 8 and the cardinality of your set is also 8, then it must be a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis.

Comment: WHat's the difference between $\mathbb{Q}( ,)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[,]$?

Comment: @monoidaltransform Well, when I write $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2},i]$ I only want to stress the fact that $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $i$ generate the field not only as an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ but also as a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. In other words, every element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ is of the form $f(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ for some polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.